# Loading MySQL data into javascript slider

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I looked around and couldn't really find an answer on how to do this so i hope you can help me out! I want to make a javascript slider where when you click the next arrow, a new set of results is displayed in the window. The data will be coming from a MySQL database, along with an image to display which depends on the data. I'm doing this with PHP, and I'm an ultra noob. If you know how to do this, or know of any examples would you please help me out? Thanks

Comment: You should look at some AJAX tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're a noob, I highly recommend you search for jQuery scripts.  There are many pre-built jQuery scripts for this type of task, and jQuery is accessible for JS neophytes.  Google is your friend in this search -- we could post links here, but there are so many possibilities for this type of task, only you'll know what you're looking for.  You might want to start with e.g. *ajax grid jquery*.  Many grid scripts can be used as a base for displaying paged MySQL data.